# Why cannot less-than-1500 users suggest new tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have question upon [mikroC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikroelektronika#Products) (it's kind of different with C), and I cannot create a new tag, so I was wondering why users with reputation points less than 1500 cannot, at least, suggest a new tag to be added to his question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does stackexchange/stackoverflow not allow new users to create tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32192/why-does-stackexchange-stackoverflow-not-allow-new-users-to-create-tags)

Comment: The very simple reason is to prevent tag pollution.

Comment: @BoltClock: I said "suggest" not "create", I believe they are not same

Comment: How exactly would such a "suggestion" work?

Comment: I would also note that having the question tagged as 'mikro-c' does the poster little good, assuming the goal is to attract attention from other mikroC users who are likely to have an answer. It wouldn't help filtering, as no one would have it as their favorite tag. The poster would be much better off putting 'mikroC' in the topic and tagging it with the much more popular 'c'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because this is not a very common scenario. New features are implemented when the higher-priority features are done, so if you want this new feature I suggest you start a new question (or edit this one) tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), where you explain what you want, and maybe give a rough workflow of how this could work.

It took a while before they made it possible for everyone to (suggest an) edit, because this is hard to get right (find the right mix between easy editing and preventing abuse). From a global view it does not seem there is a shortage of tags, and maybe this could do more harm than good ("tag pollution" is a hard thing to keep under control). There is also a simple "workaround": end your question with *"Please add the [mikro-c](/questions/tagged/mikro-c) tag to this question, I could not create it myself"*, and a higher-rep user can edit your question and add the tag for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add a comment to your question requesting that tag. If a higher rep user thinks it's reasonable he'll edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really think it is a good tag (and otherwise you shouldn't create it anyway), then you can consider writing a post on the per-site meta with your rationale why it is a good tag and with some examples where it could be used.