# Tag notability guidelines?

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider this question: [Can't get results from a JSON API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157853/cant-get-results-from-a-json-api).

It has just had a new tag, [untappd](/questions/tagged/untappd), applied to it, and the author that has created the tag has also now suggested contents for a tag wiki for it (see https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/243656 at present). There is only one question tagged as such and no other questions about it in the system.

I would consider this "untappd" social network to be an obscure resource and not likely to be used again ("too localized" as a tag). Wikipedia has rules requiring certain degree of notability before an article may stand; does Stack Overflow have such rules or guidelines? Should such a tag be permitted to remain? My inclination would be no, but I didn't want to just untag it without some discussion first.

One aspect of this question can be extended to cover Stack Overflow specifically; there might be a difference in notability guidelines on different categories; for example, languages, libraries, websites ([untappd](/questions/tagged/untappd) fitting into the last category). At this level, I suppose it might be becoming a question of suitability almost as much as notability. I feel that a website requires a lot more notability before it's suitable than a language or library would.

Comment: Also like Wikipedia, we have inclusionists and deletionists, and I'm sure you'll get input from both camps. Also refer (just so they're in the Linked list): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107992/create-a-new-tag-for-a-piece-of-software-with-limited-user-base and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/on-guidelines-to-tagging-and-avoiding-unnecessary-tags and (old) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32192/why-does-stack-overflow-not-allow-new-users-to-create-tags

Comment: In this case, the new tag will be automatically deleted about six months from now! Supposedly [a script runs every month that automatically deletes tags six months after they're created if they've only been used once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418). (This is also listed in *[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/99024#99024)*, at 2010-05-30.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notability is irrelevant except insofar as it affects usefulness.  Tags are useful if they provide a distinct category of questions, so that anyone interested in the subject can see all relevant questions.  (In some cases tags that are only useful when used in conjunction with others are allowed, at least on other sites, but that's a bit tangential.)

So the questions to ask are (in addition to the two in Joachim's answer):

1. Does the tag create a meaningful category that people will use?  ([errors](/questions/tagged/errors) does not, for example.)
2. Is it or is it about to become applicable to a meaningful subset of questions? (No one needs to see a handful of two obscure questions.)

If this is the only question about untappd, then it fails #2.  I get two search results for `untappd` and one doesn't seem relevant.  I haven't heard of a booming interest in the site either ;)

Comment: Well _I_ have an interest in the site, but then again it's closely related to my hobby. But no, there's nothing so unique about the site that it should have its own tag.

Answer (score 2):

- Is the question itself valid for SO?
- Is the tag actually relevant to the content of the question?

If both are true and there is no other tag that is sufficiently specific, then I don't see the harm in creating a tag that is.

Worst case: it will stay the only question and we'll have a (correct, but mostly unused) tag.
Best case: ever other person who starts asking questions about this topic will find the same tag and use it, thus creating a structured repository of information about untappd.

In that *specific* case, it doesn't seem that the question (*or* the answers) are actually specific to untappd itself. In that case I wouldn't apply the tag *even* if it existed.

Comment: I could go either way with the tag being applied if it was already an existing/good tag, but I agree this question doesn't warrant its creation.

Comment: In this case how would you decide "sufficiently specific"? Because you could well end up with people arguing both ways.

Answer (score 1):

> does Stack Overflow have such rules or guidelines?

No, we don't.

But as a community member, you are free to delete the tag from the question.

A sign that it is not a good tag is indeed only having a handful of tagged questions (though every tag has to start somewhere...).

Having a tag for every site and social network out there would not be productive.